# Use environment variable in xml (in Azure ServiceDefinition xml)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, azure, environment-variables

Is it possible to use an environment variable inside the ServiceDefinition.csdef xml file itself?

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
  <ServiceDefinition name="MyService"    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
 <WorkerRole name="MyService" vmsize="Small">
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="Create.cmd config_%DeploymentId%" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" >
    <Environment>
      <Variable name="DeploymentId">
        <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/ConfigurationSettings/ConfigurationSetting[@name='DeploymentId']/@value" />
      </Variable>
    </Environment>          
  </Task>
```

...

The create.cmd batch receives the parameters as string and doesn't get replaced with the actual deployment ID value.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass in %DeploymentId% on the command line?  You can just have the code in Create.cmd reference the %DeploymentId% environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

This article might be helpful, contains a tutorial on setting environment variables inside the CSDEF: http://blog.toddysm.com/2011/03/what-environment-variables-can-you-use-in-windows-azure.html